# How to avoid too many model classes

Tags: backbone.js

The number of models has grown quickly in my application.  I'm wondering about your standard practices regarding backbone.js.  Lets say you want to create a view that requires 2 other models.  Do you create a new model class to contain the 2 models like this:

```
var m = new TheModel({
  model1: new Model1,
  model2: new Model2
});
var view = new TheView({model:m});
```

or do you just do something like:

```
var m = {
  model1: new Model1,
  model2: new Model2
};
var view = new TheView({model:m});
```

The second seems better because then I don't need the extra model class `TheModel`.  But if I mix the two methods, then in my view I have to remember which style I'm using because if I want to get access to `model1` or `model2` then there are two different ways:

```
var m1 = this.model.get('model1');
```

or this way in the second scheme:

```
var m1 = this.model.model1;
```

Which is better in your opinion??  How do you organize all the models and views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is a reason to link your models, I would not create a new model that aggregates other models.  The second option is better because you are not linking them.

I prefer to separate them even further:

```
var view = new TheView({purchases: purchasesModel, user: userModel });
```

Then, inside the view, instead of referencing `this.model`, you reference `this.purchases` and `this.user` specifically.

You see, the `model` property on the views is really just a convention.  There is nothing special about the `model` property in the view except that the `model` property will get copied automatically in the constructor.  Other than that, there is no reference to the `model` in `Backbone.View`.

Of course, this means that you need to do something with it:

```
var TheView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.purchases = options.purchases;
        this.user = options.user;
    }
});
```

This way, you are being explicit about the multiple models that you require.  I like this better than verison #2 because you are not as explicit about the requirements of the View.

Comment: And I just wanted to add that it is actually really helpful to know that `model` is just a convention and isn't anything special.

Comment: :)  Glad to help.  When in doubt, I refer to the (annotated source)[http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html].  It is really a great way to get your head around what is going on.

Comment: Wow great link!  Didn't know that existed... helps alot!

Answer (score 1):

You should use Collections in this case. Here you can read more about Collections: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-collection/